# Get the AVG of numbers and exclude the ones that match a certain text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a challenge for the advanced excel experts in here, so I am trying to get the average of some numbers but I don't want to count on that AVG the numbers that on another cell match a certain text so I am looking for help with a formula kind like "ignoring" the values that match that text on another cell.

[image: Problem picture]

Looking for the AVG of those numbers with exception of "6","7,88" since they match the "missed trade" text. (Tried AVERAGEIFS didn't worked)

Comment: See [AverageIfS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried that, the problem is that it does not ignore the values I want to ignore on the same row as the text is in a different column, for example I want the avg of all those numbers but not the 6 and 3,3 because they are on the same row as the missed trade text.

Comment: Then edit your Q to show what tried, and some sample data _as text_ (so it can be copied)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `AVERAGEIFS()` like-

```
=AVERAGEIFS(G1:G7,H1:H7,"<>missed trade")
```

[image]